# Can't set the path of the SDKs in Android Studio 3.5

Tags: android, sdk

I had Android Studio earlier version installed with needed SDKs.

I had to uninstall it and manually deleted all SDKs & Android folders from my device.

Now when I installed latest version 3.5. I can't set the path where SDKs should be downloaded and I can't install any SDKs.

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1- I open the SDK manager

2- I tap Edit right next to Android SDK location (Which is empty and beneath it a warning to specify the SDK location).

3- It opens SDK Components Setup

4- Under Android SDK Location it's set to "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Android\sdk"
Though in the window before it the SDK location is empty

5- I tried next & finish still the SDK location is empty.

6- I tried to select different location & next & finish, but it doesn't change the path in this window from what I mentioned earlier & being empty in the window before it.

7- All check boxes not working (I tap on them but they don't get checked), neither in the SDK manager window nor in the select the SDK location window.

I'm running Windows 10

I have Java 8 installed on my device but not Java SDK.

Comment: move your sdk in other driver and set that path

Comment: @jaikhambhayta I can't download any SDK because I can't set the path of the SDKS.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio     download sdk from here

Comment: @jaikhambhayta 1st I couldn't find the sdks to download. 2nd why [SDK Platform] tab is like a dead screen, I can't check / select any SDK. I can't even switch to other tabs as [SDK Tools].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved based on the answer to this question.

[Android Studio 2.3 sdk manager tabs grayed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42638326/android-studio-2-3-sdk-manager-tabs-grayed-out)

I changed the SDK path to c:\Android\SDK and the SDK Manager accepted this path, though it didn't accept other paths. This's when it offered me to download latest SDK & its components. And when it's done, the SDK Manager window is not greyed out anymore, I can check / select to download other SDKs & I can switch to other taps.